# How to populate a data grid view using a model in MVP

Tags: c#, .net, oop, binding, mvp

In a win forms application there is a grid view in the UI which should be populated with the details of branch offices of the client. There are about 50 branches. So `GetBranchDetails()` method in the `DataService` class returns a `DataSet` and the `Presenter` class passes that `DataSet` to the UI's `BindData()` method in which the `datasource` property of the grid view is set to the `DataSet` object as shown in the code.

The problem is the `DataService` is not returning a model rather it returns a `DataSet`. Can some one tell me how to use `BranchOffice` model instead of using a `DataSet` here? So that the `Model` should be returned from `DataService` and then the `presenter` will pass that `Model` to UI where the `Model` will be set as the `datasource` to the grid view. Please note that always there will be more than one branch offices!

**DataService Class**

```
        public DataTable GetBranchDetails()
        {
            string selectStatement = "SELECT ID, branch_name + ', ' + branch_add AS Branch,       area, sm, atten_status FROM Branch WHERE Status='Active'";
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new   SqlConnection(db.GetConnectionString))
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, sqlConnection))
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
           {
              ds.Tables.Add(dt);    
              sqlConnection.Open();
              da.Fill(dt);
              return dt;
           }
        }
```

**Presenter Class**

```
private void _View_ShowBranches(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowBranches();
}

private void ShowBranches()
{
    var dt = DataService.GetBranchDetails();
    this._View.BindData(dt);
}
```

**View / UI**

```
public partial class frmAttendancePoints : Form, IView
{
    public frmAttendancePoints()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    public void BindData(DataSet dt)
    {
        dgAttendancePoints.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the Json work for you?

Comment: I have not yet tried Json as I'm not familiar with it at all. But actually since this is a C# Win forms app is it a better solution over returning a ado.net DataSet?

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to convert the ADO.NET DataTable to JSON that can be presented in an MVP View:

```
 string GetJson(DataTable table)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row = null;
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in table.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(column.ColumnName.Trim(), dataRow[column]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
    }
```